# Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass) : ‘proj4string’ is not a slot in class “NULL”

Tags: r

I am having error running a buffer function. The "error messages" appears as follow:
Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass)  :
‘proj4string’ is not a slot in class “NULL”

This is my scipt:

```
a.x <- cfma[!cfma$No=="NULL",]
## internal buffer to keep all plots within the site boundary

a <- buffer(a.x, width=-120, dissolve=TRUE) #####
## crop Geoville map to the site of interest
b <- crop(lc,a)
       ## remove NA values from the raster
c <- mask(b,a)
## remove any 0 from the raster
c[c==0] <- NA
```

...

Please, is there any help?

Comment: Hi @Ink Teah and welcome to SO. To get helpful answers, it is important to provide the necessary information in your question. Without knowing what type of data you are working with (spatial object, simple feature, line, point, polygon, etc.) and what you hope to achieve, we can't answer your question. Please clarify the question and make sure you include reproducible code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.